# Waiting for Modernizr to load jQuery from a user script

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey, userscripts, modernizr

I'm working on a Google Chrome userscript which enhances a site that is loading [jQuery](http://jquery.com) via [Modernizr's `.load()` method](http://modernizr.com/docs/#load).

I'll be using the site's jQuery instance but the userscript begins execution before jQuery has been loaded.

Is there a deterministic way to intercept Modernizr's `load()` / `complete` mechanism from a Greasemonkey script or userscript?

Or is polling for `window[jQuery]` / `'$' in window`, etc the only solution?

(I'm trying to avoid loading my own instance of jQuery and with polling I sometimes miss the first changes to the document I want to intercept using [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver).)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what u trying to do, but below script might help you. It will defer any inline script inside your html page and will execute after all script have been loading by modernizr on return.

Define below line before modernizr load function.

```
docready=[],$=function(){return{ready:function(fn){docready.push(fn)}}},
```

Write below script on modernizr load complete

```
$ = jQuery;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    for(n in docready) docready[n]();
});
```

Comment: How do I "define a line before modernizr load function" in a userscript? All the modernizr code is in the 3rd party website whose code I cannot alter. Maybe I'm just misunderstanding something.

Comment: Just before you load the modernizr script, in your userscript.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't make it clear that I'm not loading modernizr in my userscript, the 3rd party site loads it directly via a conventional `<script>` tag in its `<head>`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to wait for window.onload which fires when EVERYTHING has loaded.

Document-end and document-idle are both guaranteed to run after the entire DOM is parsed, which is the usual thing script developers are interested in having occurred. If for some reason you really need your script to run after window.onload, you can check the document.readystate property. If it is "complete", then you can assume onload has occurred. If it isn't, then you can listen for onload.

Comment: I had the feeling that the site only started to load jQuery once it got `onload` but I'll go back and check for that. Thanks...

Comment: Sadly I only get internet connectivity now and then at the moment so I haven't gotten back to this yet and my code still uses polling which works so far but the nondeterminacy of it still bugs me.

Comment: Ah right on.  I look forward to seeing what you come up with :)